# Click event not firing! (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a click handler for my View, but it seems like the view's `el` `$('#modal')` when targeted by the click event handler does not fire when clicked. But when I target any child of `$('modal')`, the click event is triggered on clicking.

I am guessing `$('#modal')` is not considered as part of the view, so click event handlers defined within `events` does not work on it. If so, is there another way around it?

```
ModalView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#modal'),

    template: _.template( $('#tpl_modal').html() ),

    events: {
        'click #modal': 'closeModal'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'renderSimilarPosts', 'closeModal');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        $(this.el).fadeIn('fast').append( this.template( this.model.toJSON( this.model ) ) );
    },

    closeModal: function() {
        // some code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

instead of:

```
'click #modal': 'closeModal'
```

Try:

```
"click": 'closeModal'
```

Backbone events uses jQuery's `delegate` function, which applies the handler (in this case `closeModal`) to all children who match a given selector (in this case `click #modal`). Since with `click #modal` we are looking within #modal for a child named #modal, no elements are being found.

Take a look into [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to see what I mean.